# Error when runnig a website from azure

Tags: azure, model-view-controller

I have built my mvc5 project with webApi's, when running from VS2013 the website works fine, I have deployed my project to azure, so when I run the website from azure it gives an error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

what is going wrong?what am I missing

Comment: What libraries are you using? What is the version of the System.Web.Mvc referenced to your project (check under properties)?
Current version is 5.2.2, so maybe one of other libraries your website is using depends on older version of System.Web.Mvc

Comment: thank you problem solved I had to set the copy local to true

Comment: This solves the problem but you would be better off [enabling nuget package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) and let azure restore packages during deployment. Then you don't need "copy local to true".